# Looking for a short comic story about a robot trying to save a human pilot but bound by the 3 laws

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots

I remember reading this short comic about 2 years ago. The look of the book seemed pretty new. I remember that it was a hard-cover comic. The picture on the cover was the robot with some kind of a small hologram in its hand. I have no idea when this story was written.

A shuttle has just crashed in a desert of a distant planet. The pilot of the shuttle sends the robot looking for help and/or water.

The robot then leaves the shuttle and ventures alone into this new world. He was bound by the [3 laws of robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics):

The robot then encounters a young girl and her mother and they start bonding. I know they spend A LOT of time together because of the 3 laws, he feels compelled to help them.

That's about all I remember except for the very last scene when :

> The little girl was either old or naturally died and that the hologram he got in his hand on the cover is the little girl. The robot then return to his shuttle with water and supplies only to find the pilot in a skeletal
>  state, the shuttle covered in rust and under meters of sand. Years
>  have passed and that robot was unaware of how time had gone by.

Any hint would be helpful!

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've Finally found it !

The title is Saving Human Being and it is written by Xiaoyu Zhang

It is a very short story with a lot of beautiful graphics. I recommend it to anyone and it is translated in many languages!

[image] [image]